# Does ffmpeg allow for hr:min:sec:frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, timecodes

I am looking to concat a video and an image using ffmpeg and was wondering if when cutting the video I can cut it with a timecode that uses seconds:frames (00:00:23:4)instead of seconds.miliseconds (00:00:23.43) and then concat it with seconds:frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, see the [time duration syntax documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) for accepted syntax.

You can use the reciprocal of the output frame rate instead. For example, frame #5 for a constant output frame rate of 25 is `5*(1/25)=0.2`.